# Rails process every request twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I've got very weird problem with Rails using Spree.

Every single request is being processed twice. It's not problem with AJAX as single CURL request is also processed twice. It's not problem with logs either, as actions really takes place twice.

Problem exists only in production environment, both on Heroku and locally.

Example log:

```
2014-04-06T06:45:48.969394+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/spree/api/orders/R657018514/line_items host=xxx.xxx.com request_id=75ac3584-f33e-48fe-b6ce-d898120f8b57 fwd="185.12.21.77" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=399ms status=201 bytes=1097
2014-04-06T06:45:48.952672+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/spree-78f129b6d6f5/api/app/views/spree/api/orders/show.v1.rabl (120.9ms)
2014-04-06T06:45:48.959453+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 201 Created in 381ms (Views: 93.4ms | ActiveRecord: 188.8ms)
2014-04-06T06:45:48.959460+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 201 Created in 381ms (Views: 93.4ms | ActiveRecord: 188.8ms)
2014-04-06T06:45:48.958355+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/spree-78f129b6d6f5/api/app/views/spree/api/orders/show.v1.rabl (120.9ms)

Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-06 08:55:29 +0200
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-06 08:55:29 +0200
Processing by Spree::HomeController#index as HTML
Processing by Spree::HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered spree/home/index.html.erb within spree/layouts/spree_application (0.8ms)
  Rendered spree/home/index.html.erb within spree/layouts/spree_application (0.8ms)
```

Gemfile.rb:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.3'

gem 'newrelic_rpm'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 4.0.0'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
  gem 'compass',                      '= 0.12.2'
  gem 'compass-rails',                '~> 1.1.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'pry-rails'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

gem 'handlebars_assets'

gem 'spree', :github => "methyl/spree", :require => false
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise'
```

production.rb

```
Aimer::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=31536000"

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  config.assets.js_compressor  = :uglifier
  config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Defaults to nil and saved in location specified by config.assets.prefix
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = false

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  # config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
end
```

Comment: How do you know it's not the logs? I find it highly impossible to have 2 requests with exact same rendering time, is that the case for all requests?

Comment: I receive emails twice, AFAIK it's for every request.

Comment: Not only are the log entries showing *exact* same processing time, two have been written within 7 microseconds of each other. Whatever the problem is, the code shown does not cover it. I might suspect accidental double-calls to some middleware component, perhaps due to registering it twice.

Answer (score 1):

@Giannis, you were right, logs was only duplicated, and cause of double emails was somewhere else, probably in Sendgrid config.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you were using heroku for deployment before, and later you started to use any other instance for deployment.

Try commenting `gem 'rails_12factor'` once and do bundle install, then check once.